# how to solve screen not functioning properly

Tags: tecno-n3

how to solve screen not functioning properly
my phone is Tecno L8, and some parts of the screen are not responding to touch.
and its also popping up things not pressed.
how do i solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Your digitizer is likely broken. You can either send it back to the original manufacturer for repair or find a third party source that can do it for you.

You may just want to consider replacing the phone.